# returning a big array of data VS stuffing a referenced argument in PHP

Tags: php

I need an expert opinion on that matter. Let say I am fetching a lot of data (really a lot) from a database.

Are the two functions equivalent regarding the performance ?

```
function fetch_1 ($id) {
  // ... fetch data based on the id
  return $results;
}

function fetch_2 ($id, &$fetch) {
  // ... fetch data based on the id
  $fetch = $results;
}
```

?

Comment: Is your script running out of memory then?

Comment: @MatthewDaly nah, optimization FTW

Comment: @MatthewDaly is it not a memory question, just an execution time performance one.

Comment: Ah, if it was a memory issue I was going to suggest looking at generators, but if the issue isn't running out of memory then they probably aren't going to help.

Comment: Definite answer: you should do neither nor! This approach requires you to load _all_ results into memory, maybe even duplicating them. That will not scale! Instead you need to process the result set in a sequential manner, by iterating over each result entry and processing it right away so that your memory footprint stays constant no matter how big the result set is.